# Render Turkish Character contains Angularjs view

Tags: angularjs

I have turkish character problem in rendered angularjs view.

```
Normal state, there aren't turkish problem, i added 
`<meta charset="utf-8" />` to index.html
```

Turkish character problem is in the angular rendered view.

ü ğ ç ı ö ş İ Ç Ü Ğ Ş letters was viewed as ?????

How can i resolve this problem ?

[image]

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 80px;margin-right: 10px" ng-click="submit()">Kaydet</button>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Iptal  ü ğ ç ı ö ş İ Ç Ü Ğ Ş</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you make sure the file containing those characters is actually encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks for reply Nikos.
Yes, i'm sure, i added charset utf-8 in head tags.
I think this problem about with angularjs view render because the problem not exist out of view rendered area. This problem seen only  rendered view area

Comment: Hi, actually I mean the encoding of the *file*; the header may state it is UTF-8, but the file is actually saved as ISO-8859-9. You can try opening it in an editor (not plain Notepad :) - try Notepad++ on Windows) and check the encoding (e.g. menu "Encoding" for Notepad++).

Answer (score 3):

Check your xxxview.html file encoding or .js file encoding. if your are using visual studio, you can change file encoding Advance Save Option... in File Menu. You can choose Unicode UTF-8. It works for me.